# Lazy DataTable rendering is very slow

Tags: performance, primefaces, datatable, lazy-loading

## Environment:

- PrimeFaces 5.1
- Mojarra 2.2.2
- Spring 4.0.2

## Problem:

I use a `p:dataTable` with `lazy=true` and I have implemented a LazyDataModel.
All works perfectly well (pagination, filtering, etc.), but it is very slow...

The `load` method is called, it performes the call to the DB and returns in 3sec max. But after that, it takes up to **20sec** for the page to load (render?)...

For information, the page loads through ajax: a listener give informations to the LazyModel (setters), then change the page to insert (`ui:insert`, value stored in the controller), and finally update the form (`update=":form"`).

After debugging it seems that I have no control on this...

## Code:

```
<p:dataTable id="storeTable"
        value="#{dashboard.stores}"
        var="store"
        lazy="true"
        paginator="true" rows="30"
        paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
        paginatorPosition="bottom">

    ...
    <!-- Columns -->
    ...
    <c:forEach var="date" items="#{dashboard.days}">
        <c:set var="day" value="#{store.getDay(date)}"/>

        <p:column styleClass="store-day open-#{store.isAmOpen(date.date)} store-day-available-#{store.isAvailable(date.date)} #{store.storeKey} #{day.date.time} am" 
                width="30">
            <h:outputText value="&#160;" title="#{day.amComment}" />
            <h:outputText styleClass="store" value="#{store.storeKey}" style="display: none" />
            <h:outputText styleClass="date" value="#{day.date.time}" style="display: none" />
            <h:outputText styleClass="am_pm" value="am" style="display: none" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column styleClass="store-day open-#{store.isPmOpen(date.date)} store-day-available-#{store.isAvailable(date.date)} #{store.storeKey} #{day.date.time} pm" 
                width="30">
            <h:outputText value="&#160;" title="#{day.pmComment}" />

            <h:outputText styleClass="store" value="#{store.storeKey}" style="display: none" />
            <h:outputText styleClass="date" value="#{day.date.time}" style="display: none" />
            <h:outputText styleClass="am_pm" value="pm" style="display: none" />
        </p:column>

    </c:forEach>

</p:dataTable>
```

Relevant code of the controller:

```
@Controller("dashboard")
@Scope("session")
public class DashboardController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1971543164359627877L;

    private LazyStoreWebModel stores;
    // Some more attributes

    @PostConstruct
    public void postCtr() {
        stores = new LazyStoreWebModel(restit);
        update();
    }

    private void updateGroupList() {
        groupList.clear();
        groupList.addAll(groupDao.findByCountry(countryFilter));
    }

    public void updateStoreChainTypeList() {
        storeChainTypeList.clear();
        storeChainTypeList.addAll(storeTypeDao.findByCountry(countryFilter));
    }

    public void updateStoreZoneList() {
        storeZoneList.clear();
        storeZoneList.addAll(storeZoneDao.findByCountryAndChainType(
                countryFilter, chainTypeFilter));
    }

    public void updateStoreRegionList() {
        storeRegionList.clear();
        if (storeZoneFilter != null) {
            storeRegionList.addAll(storeRegionDao.findByCountryAndZone(
                    countryFilter, storeZoneFilter));
        }
    }

    public void updateDays() {
        days.clear();
        days.addAll(calendar.generateListDateFromMonthAndYear(
                yearFilter, monthFilter.getCode()));
        stores.setYear(yearFilter);
        stores.setMonth(monthFilter.getCode());

        Collections.sort(days);
    }

    public void update() {    
        updateGroupList();
        updateStoreChainTypeList();
        updateStoreZoneList();
        updateStoreRegionList();
        updateDays();

        stores.setCountry(countryFilter);
        stores.setChainType(chainTypeFilter);
        stores.setRegion(storeRegionFilter);
        stores.setZone(storeZoneFilter);
    }

    public LazyDataModel<StoreWeb> getStores() {
        return stores;
    }
}
```

The LazyDataModel

```
public class LazyStoreWebModel extends LazyDataModel<StoreWeb> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4318420518897167924L;

    private RestitService restit;

    private Country country;
    private StoreChainType chainType;
    private StoreZone zone;
    private StoreRegion region;
    private Integer storeIntFlagFilter;
    private Integer year;
    private Integer month;

    public LazyStoreWebModel(RestitService restit) {
        this.restit = restit;
    }

    @Override
    public StoreWeb getRowData(String key) {
        try {
            return restit.visualisationStoreById(key, year, month);
        } catch (CalendarException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotExistStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StoreWeb sto = new StoreWeb();
        sto.setStoreDesc("Should be null");
        sto.setStoreKey("NULL:" + key);
        return sto;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(StoreWeb sto) {
        return sto.getStoreKey();
    }

    @Override
    public List<StoreWeb> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
            SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> fieldFilters) {
        List<StoreWeb> result = new ArrayList<StoreWeb>();

        Map<String, Object> mainFilters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mainFilters.put(RestitService.COUNTRY_KEY, country);
        mainFilters.put(RestitService.CHAIN_TYPE_KEY, chainType);
        mainFilters.put(RestitService.ZONE_KEY, zone);
        mainFilters.put(RestitService.REGION_KEY, region);
        mainFilters.put(RestitService.INT_FLAG_KEY, storeIntFlagFilter);
        mainFilters.put(RestitService.YEAR_KEY, year);
        mainFilters.put(RestitService.MONTH_KEY, month);

        try {
            result.addAll(restit.load(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder,
                    mainFilters, fieldFilters));
        } catch (CalendarException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotExistStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setRowCount(restit.count(mainFilters, fieldFilters));
        return result;
    }
}
```

The `restit` attribute do the calls to the DB.

Any idea?

Thanks.

## Edits:

1. Added relevant code of the controller
2. Added code of the LazyDataModel
3. Added code inside the HTML: Problem seems to come from the amount of columns (60+), more precisely from the quantity of attribute access done to build those.

Comment: Could you add more code such as the relevant part of your controller?

Comment: @MathieuCastets Done, but I don't think it will help. The problem comes after the LazyDataModel is returned and call.

Comment: Indeed, what would be useful is to see your `LazyStoreWebModel` (especially your load method)

Comment: @MathieuCastets Done. I also added others overrided methods.

Comment: If you have 500 columns and in each column a PrimeFaces selectOneMenu, this is to be expected and a browser issue... Or in other words: provide more detail (what did you debug) and investigate WHERE the delay is... (use e.g. a phaselistener)

Comment: @Kukeltje It seems to be the type of issue you said. Is there any solution or advice to avoid this slowness?

Comment: if you have row/cell editing, use the native inputs (see PF documentation). That helps, but to many columns is still bad. Redesigning the UI is then best

Comment: @Kukeltje I have just done some logging and the phase `RENDER_RESPONSE 6` is the slowest (>15s). So it seems it's while rendering the dataTable... But I can't suppress columns, it's a calendar by half day => about 60 columns...

Comment: Do you load master-detail data 'lazy' from a database? In that case it might be that you get lots and lots of queries (in the RENDER_RESPONSE phase since that is where the datatable does al its work)